Counting them 100 years later
At first
A was 1
B was 1
C was 2
D was 1
E was 3
F was 2
G was 1
M was 1
P was 1
R was 2
S was 3
T was 1
W was 3
100 years later
A is 4
B is 6
C is 7
D is 1
E is 1
F is 2
G is 1
H is 2
J is 1
M is 2
R is 3
S is 6
T is 5
V is 1
W is 3
What are we counting?

We are counting

 The number of sports starting with a certain letter in both the 1924 and 2024 Paris Olympics!

List one

 Represents the events in the 1924 Paris Olympics since if we count all the sports starting with each letter regarding Swimming, Diving and Water Polo as individual sports we end up with the list.


 


The second list

 Represents the events of the 2024 Olympics 100 years later… If you look at the events of the 2024 Paris Olympics and count all the sports starting with each letter you end up with the second list.

